# Javascript modifier keys that works on both Mac/PC?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I've found some threads about this, but non that completely answers my questions.

I'm a Mac user and know very little about what the key commands work on PC, but I assume that most things that you use the CMD key for on Mac is the same on PC but with the CTRL key?

In my web app I want to let the user use key commands for things like save, new, show/hide etc. Since the browser by default is using CMD+S to save the page and CMD+N to open a new window and CMD+H to hide the window I guess it would be bad practice to replace that (if even possible). And since the same applies to the CTRL key on PC I guess that SHIFT and ALT are the only options left, if not having it work differently on Mac/PC.

SHIFT and ALT don't feel as key commandy though unfortunately and using single letters seem too risky for mistakes.

How is this usually solved in web apps? Is there a list where I can see standard commands in browsers to avoid and which ones can or cannot be replaced?

If I go for CTRL as modifier on Mac, is the metaKey an option on PC or is that not considered standard?

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of javascript libraries. The ones related to the browsers and the ones related to the server(nodejs).

If you try to do something in the browser, then you could do something like

```
$("input").keydown(function(){
    if (event.keyCode === 12) {
        $("input").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
});
```

Where the keycode, in this case is the "enter" key.
To obtain a keycode: https://keycode.info/.

The events you want make modifications in the operating system behavior, which is not allowed from a web browser for security reasons.

If you want to forget about browsers and give it a try with node here it is a tutorial:

https://thisdavej.com/making-interactive-node-js-console-apps-that-listen-for-keypress-events/

Comment: <kbd>Enter</kbd>'s `e.keyCode` is `13`, not `12`. Also, `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are both deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also make the code easier to understand, as now it would be `e.key ==='Enter'`. Just keep in mind some old browsers used some non-standard codes, so left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE and Legacy Edge they would be `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 